# How can I get my canvas element value with in the div?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to get the context of myCanvas that is placed under the  tag when i'm trying get the context value I'm getting an error saying that canvas not defined??? How can I resolve this issue???

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 < body >
 < div class ="div-left-column" id ="display" onload="make_base()" >
 < img id="scream" src="/home/openstack/harikrishna/html/tower.jpg" alt="The Scream"        width="50" height="50" >
 < img id ="gray" src ="/home/openstack/harikrishna/html/tower-gray.jpg" width = 50 height = 50/ >
 < canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" />
 < input type ="button" id="clear" name ="clear" value ="clear" />
 < /div >
 < /body >
```

JS:

```
   function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {
      var elm = document.getElementById(childID);
      var parent = elm ? elm.parentNode : {};
      return (parent.id && parent.id === containerID) ? elm : {};
     }
    e = GetElementInsideContainer("display", "myCanvas");
 var canvas = e.id;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var image = document.getElementById("scream");
 var clicks = 0;
 var lastClick = [0, 0];
 canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", getPosition, false);

function make_base(){
 var img  = new Image();
 var img2 = new Image();
 img.src = "/home/openstack/harikrishna/html/tower.jpg";
 img2.src = "/home/openstack/harikrishna/html/tower-gray.jpg";
 img.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(img, 10,10,30,30);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(40,40);
   ctx.lineTo(80,250);
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.drawImage(img, 80,250,30,30);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(110,250);
   ctx.lineTo(210,20);
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.drawImage(img,180,20,30,30);
  }
 img2.onload = function(){
   ctx.drawImage(img2,250,200,30,30);
 }  
}

function getPosition(event)
{
   var x = event.x;
   var y = event.y;
   x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
   y -= canvas.offsetTop;
   //alert("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
   ctx.clearRect(250,200,30,30);
   ctx.drawImage(image,x,y,30,30);
}

 document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }, false);
```

Comment: which browser did you try.? Did you include the HTML 5 Doctype ..? can you make it fiddle.?

Comment: I'm using Google chrome @Manoj and here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CKUQ4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(e.id);
```

[See The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khursheed_Ali/CKUQ4/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You  mentioned only the id name not that DOM element.

[Try the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/4wBzg/)

Code:

```
   e = GetElementInsideContainer("display", "myCanvas");
   console.log(e.id); //here geeting only id name
   var canvas = document.getElementById(e.id);
   console.log(canvas); //here geeting only DOM element
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```